# What tools do I need to make a hole in an exterior stucco wall?

Tags: exterior, stucco

My dehumidifier fills up too quickly so I need to attach a hose to it that drains outside.

The exterior wall is stucco.

What I do need for drilling the hole (drill bit types, etc.) and for sealing around the hose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A carbide hole saw for the stucco. And that will work for the interior (drywall I presume?) as well. Always be aware that there could be pipes and/or wires in the wall where you are drilling. Seal around the pipes with a high quality latex caulk.

Comment: Fortunately there isn't an interior wall in my case. Just bare studs on the inside. But I'm sure others with this question won't have such an unusable setup.

Comment: Depending on the size of the hole, a normal masonry drill bit and either a hammer drill (slow!) or rotary hammer drill (fast, but most people don’t need to own one) will work. If using a drill bit, drill from the outside toward the interior to prevent unsightly blowout. (The holesaw doesn’t have this problem to the same extent, but it wouldn’t hurt.)